# Installing satellite dish to point to local zenith

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics

After receiving help on my previous post ([Stopping/reducing wobbliness in threaded rod](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25999/stopping-reducing-wobbliness-in-threaded-rod)), I've decided to come back and ask another question: how can I actually hold the satellite dish into place? I don't wish to have the dish steerable (as this will probably require too much work considering the size of the dish), but I want it to *at least* be able to point ("look") directly upwards (to local zenith). The dish weights 16kg and has a diameter of 1.5 meters.

This is where I plan on installing the dish:
[image]

As it seems, there's nothing the dish has to offer for this kind of things (I got it used from someone who no longer needed it):
[image]
[image]
[image]

Any ideas on how to hold the dish in place to point to local zenith would be appreciated!

Comment: You suggested nuts before, so why not?

Comment: @SolarMike Could you explain how nuts could be used to keep the dish in place? Where would I use nuts?

Comment: You stated "held the threaded rod from the little hole in the center of the dish (again, using nuts)"...

Comment: @SolarMike Yeah, but where am I going to put the nuts to hold what? That's how I'm visualizing the dish, could you point me to where I'd place the nuts? Because I don't really understand your visualization.. https://i.imgur.com/LbhHB3E.png

Comment: I was hoping you knew what you had planned when you said you were using nuts...

Comment: I am using nuts to hold the rod from the center of the dish so the feed stays in place but I'm trying to find a way for the entire dish reflector to point upwards.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89827/discussion-between-coto-thearcher-and-solar-mike).

Comment: stand a table in the white area in the top picture ... place the dish on the table

Comment: There will not be a geostationary satellite at local zenith unless you are on the equator. At any other latitude your satellite dish will need to point off vertical by an angle equal to your latitude. Similarly the azimuth will be a non-zero value unless the satellite is on your longitude.

Comment: @Transistor I've been using the antenna for radio astronomy, not satellite communications.

Comment: That's propably worth mentioning in the question. It sounds like you could just rest the assembled dish on three blocks then.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use cinderblocks and place plastic anchors to attach to your antenna.

Basically you make three short pedestals with cinderblocks and cement. No need to penetrate the roofing and worry about leaks.

This is provided your antenna is out of view and wont be a like a sore eye.

or you can search eBay for brackets.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with a sketch or something? I don't really understand what you're suggesting.